# Pointer-Interconvertible Types and Arrays of Unions

Tags: c++, c++20

If I have a `union`.

```
struct None {};

template<typename T>
union Storage {
    /* Ctors and Methods */

    T obj;
    None none;
};
```

[`pointer-interconvertible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) types means it is legal to perform the following conversion:

```
Storage<T> value(/* ctor args */);
T* obj = static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(&value));
```

It is legal to treat an array of `Storage<T>` as an array of `T`?

```
Storage<T> values[20] = { /* initialisation */ };
T* objs = static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(values));

for(auto i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    objs[i].method(); // Is this pointer access legal?
}
```

Comment: Practically speaking, the size of `Storage<T>` may be greater than the size of `T` (depending on other union members), so `T` instances inside an array of `Storage` may not be contiguous. So the standard must be prohibiting this somewhere, for this reason if nothing else; it has no hope of actually working.

Comment: From the language lawyer perspective, I think it fails like this. Pointer arithmetic is only defined for pointers into an array. `objs` is a pointer to a single `T`, not to an array of `T`s; you can do `objs[0]` to access that `T` instance, and `&objs[1]` to create a past-the-end pointer, but not `objs[i]` for any other value of `i`.

Comment: My understanding is roughly the same in terms of language lawyering. I'm mostly interested in this specific case, as `constexpr` doesn't allow the usual tricks of using a byte buffer.

Comment: Your example doesn't use `constexpr` anywhere. Where and how does it enter the picture?

Comment: Sorry, the question initially gave some context but decided to get rid of it as its not really relevant to the core question. Removed the flag.

Comment: Well, the core question has been answered, I think. What do you believe is special about "this specific case" that the general considerations may not apply to it?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: `&objs+1`, yes, but not `&objs[1]` since that would form an lvalue for a nonexistent object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not legal. The only thing that may be treated as an array with regards to pointer-arithmetic is an array (and the hypothetical single-element array formed by an object that is not element of an array). So the "array" relevant to the pointer arithmetic in `objs[i]` here is the hypothetical single-element array formed by `obj` of the first array element, since it is not itself element of an array. For `i >= 1`, `objs[i]` will not point to an object and so `method` may not be called on it.

Practically, there will be an issue in particular if `T`'s size and the size of the union don't coincide, since even the arithmetic on the addresses will be off in this case. There is no guarantee that the two sizes coincide (even if `None` has `sizeof` and `alignof` equal to `1`).

Aside from that issue, I doubt that compilers actually make use of this undefined behavior for optimization purposes. I can't guarantee it though.

Also note that you are only allowed to access `obj` through the pointer obtained by the cast if `obj` is the active member of the union, meaning that `obj` is the member which was initialized in the example.

You indicate that you intend to use this in a constant expression, in which case the compiler is required to diagnose the undefined behavior and is likely to reject such a program, regardless of the practical considerations about the optimizer.

Also, in a constant expression a cast from `void*` to a different object type (or a `reinterpret_cast`) is not allowed. So `static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void*>(values));` will cause that to fail anyway. Although that is simply remedied by just taking a pointer to the union member directly (e.g. `&values[0].obj`). There is no reason to use the casts here.